# How to destroy/remove/unbind SnapSVG.js

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Is there a method to destroy the SnapSVG object. 
I'm working on an ajax application with many SnapSVG objects and I want the removed snapsvg's as they are removed from the DOM.

Is element.remove() sufficient enough for garbage collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation points to [`Element.remove()`](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.remove). It even returns the object that you attempt to remove.

Comment: Is element.remove() sufficient enough for garbage collection?

Comment: @MathiasValentin the function is made specifically to remove content so if it doesn't handle that it's probably a bug. There is a closed issue of this on [SnapSVGs GitHub](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/241). Good luck!

Comment: **Thanks** for sharing the issue link and for your help!